# I am trying to concatenate 2 CSV using pandas but the last column always gets " "

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

When saving the file, the last column *column* becomes `"column"` . I have tried many things but I cannot get it fixed. I think it kinda gets the format of `CSV` and when I open it as a `CSV` in Excel last column gets displayed normally without `""`.

Old Headers:
[image: old headers]

Produced Headers:
[image: produced headers]

Here is my python code.

```
li = []

for path in paths:
    data = pd.read_csv(path,encoding='utf-8',lineterminator='\n')
    li.append(data)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame.to_csv(new_file_path, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: What are the headers of the original CSVs? Could they possibly have the last column as "column" instead of column? Remember, just like the output file, the original file might also have the "" even though it doesn't show in Excel. You can either use a text editor to check or get python to print the name of the last column of each file on the screen?

Comment: please don't paste images of your headers; just text will do (and will make it easier for us to help you). Also, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).